# Spring boot override suffix of war file name

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to define a war name to correspond custom naming convention. Currently, 2 war files are generated: `app-name.war` and `app-name-boot.war`
However, I want to override the `-boot` suffix, e.g. the war to be named app-name-executable.war
I've tried to define it this way

```
<finalName>${artifactId}-executable</finalName>
```

But then the app-name-executable-boot is generated. So how can I override the boot suffix for runnable war?

Comment: Have you added this to <build> section ?

Comment: I did, it worked, just not the way I need - boot suffix remains, -executable suffix is added

Comment: Use maven war plugin and specify name

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I personally used this code block:

```
<build>
        <finalName>lebab-executable</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

The output was two files inside target:

- lebab-executable.war and
- lebab-executable.war.original